# emmet force default cursor position after expansion

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I am using following emmet snippet on VS Code:

```css
{<!DOCTYPE html>}>html[lang='${lang}']>(head>meta[charset='${charset}']+meta[http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'][content='IE=edge']+meta[name='viewport'][content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0']+(title>{${title}${1}})+script+style{.one{\}})+(body>div.one)
```

There is a tab stop after title `title>{${title}${1}}` which places the cursor by default after text `title|`. It expands like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>title|</title>
  <script></script>
  <style>.one{}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="one"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the cursor inside css class, in between curly braces, `.one{|}`.

So I put tab stop inside the class like `.one{${1}\}}`:

```css
{<!DOCTYPE html>}>html[lang='${lang}']>(head>meta[charset='${charset}']+meta[http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'][content='IE=edge']+meta[name='viewport'][content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0']+(title>{${title}})+script+style{.one{${1}\}})+(body>div.one)
```

But after expansion the curser is placed between script tag instead. `<script>|</script>`.

1. how can I get the curser to be inside `.one{|}` after expansion?
2. also, can I put line break inside text like `.one{<linebreak>|<linebreak>}`?

Comment: If you tab once it does where you want.  If this is something you use frequently it should be a snippet - much easier to get correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same behaviour you are seeing in vscode.  Note that if you `tab` once the cursor does go to where you want.  It may be a bug.

If this form is something you use a lot consider making it into a snippet.  It is a lot clearer to reason about and the tabstop placement does work as expected in vscode.  And you get a linebreak wherever you make a new line, so a linebreak can go anywhere.

Example snippet:

```
"html9": {
  "prefix": "html9",               // whatever prefix you want
  "body": [
    "<!DOCTYPE html>",             // need to escape "'s
    "<html lang=\"en\">",
    "<head>",
    "\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">",  // \t for a tab

    "\t<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">",
    "\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0\">",
    "\t<title>title|</title>",
    "\t<script></script>",

    // "\t<style>.one{$1}</style>",
    "\t<style>.$1{$2}</style>",      // tabstop $1 for class name

    "</head>",
    "<body>",

    // "\t<div class=\"one\"></div>",
    "\t<div class=\"$1\"></div>",   // tabstop $1 for class name

    "</body>",
    "</html>"
  ]
}
```

See [Defining your own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).

[image: html snippet]